# Why can't I choose to set up Internet Sharing to computers using AirPort?

Tags: wifi, internet-sharing, android

I'm using OSX 10.9. I'm trying to set up Internet Sharing to connect my Android to my Mac directly over Wi-Fi. Every tutorial I've come across (including [the one published by Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10740)) mentions checking a box for "AirPort" in a "To computers using" list. However, the option is simply not available on my machine:

[image: missing option]

I have a few related questions:

1. Why isn't the AirPort option available?
2. Is there anything I can do to make it available?
3. If there isn't, how can I work around it to finish setting up Internet Sharing so I can connect my Android and my Mac directly over Wi-Fi?

Comment: As you are already using WiFi to connect your MacBook to the Internet, why can't you connect your phone to the same WLAN directly (without using the MacBook as a middle man)?

Comment: I live on a college campus where they have some kind of security or copyright-infringement prevention software that prevents a particular program I want to use from working, so I want to create a LAN with just my phone and my laptop as a workaround.

Comment: Do you just want to interact between your Mac and your phone or do you need to access the Internet from your phone?

Comment: I want to interact between my phone and my computer. I don't need Internet access. This question is about the specific problem I'm having: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64130/sync-spotify-local-files-in-a-network-that-blocks-the-service

Comment: Internet Sharing is the wrong tool then, you want to use an adhoc WiFi network (see answer below).

Comment: As per my comment below, I can't use ad-hoc networks because I'm using an Android. Articles I've read online suggest that Internet sharing is a workaround in my specific case.

Answer (score 7):

The option is not available because you have selected to share your connection from Wi-Fi.

You can't share your connection from Wi-Fi to Wi-Fi. Use an alternative method of obtaining a connection to the internet (e.g. Ethernet) so that the internet connection can be shared over Wi-Fi.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a second WiFi adapter, via USB.

Comment: that sucks, there should be a way to share wifi over wifi, i want to use my macbook as a range extender

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't want to actually share your internet connection but just establish a WiFi link between the Mac and your phone the answer is to create an ad-hoc network.

To do this go to the WiFi pizza slice in the menu bar and select "Create Network..."

This brings up a dialog that allows you to name the network and set the security type. I set the security type to 128-bit WEP, type in 13 characters and then click "Create".

You will now be able to connect to this network on your phone and you will have a small LAN between the two.

Note that 128-bit WEP is not terribly secure and can be hacked given time. Change the password frequently and you should be OK but don't rely on it being secure.

Comment: This is a good idea. Unfortunately, my phone, an Android, can't connect to ad-hoc networks. Google never implemented that feature, to many users' frustrations. (More info at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/does-any-version-of-android-support-ad-hoc-connections)

Comment: Gee, what can I say? Complain to Google.